# Haskell list comprehension predicate order

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm very new to Haskell and am trying to do some stuff with algebraic groups. My first function is just to take an operation and a set and find all the members of the set that can be produced by performing that operation on a pair of that same set's members. This is my code for this:

```
group' f xs = [a | a <- xs, a <- combSet]
    where combSet = [f x y | x <- xs, y <- xs]
```

However, this code just returns the set of members of combSet, ignoring the `a <- xs` predicate:

```
*Main> group' (*) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8,10,3,6,9,12,15,4,8,12,16,20,5,10,15,20,25,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8,10,3,6,9,12,15,4,8,12,16,20,5,10,15,20,25,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8,10,3,6,9,12,15,4,8,12,16,20,5,10,15,20,25,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8,10,3,6,9,12,15,4,8,12,16,20,5,10,15,20,25,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8,10,3,6,9,12,15,4,8,12,16,20,5,10,15,20,25]
```

But when I switch the order of the comprehension predicates, to

```
group' f xs = [a | a <- combSet, a <- xs]
    where combSet = [f x y | x <- xs, y <- xs]
```

it returns the correct values, but the list is way bigger than expected:

```
*Main> group' (*) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens, or if I've done something stupid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a predicate to begin with. You have two lists, `xs` and `combSet` you take your elements from. So let us check the behaviour with a simpler example:

```
example = [a | a <- [1,2,3], a <- [4,5,6]]
```

This will lead to `concat $ replicate 3 [4,5,6]`, i.e. `[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6]`. Note that there is no element from the first list, the later binding of `a` ***shadows*** the previous.

We can the code above as "for all elements in the list `[1,2,3]`: name the current element a and then for all elements in the list `[4,5,6]`: name the current element in the list also a (and forget the previous variant therefore) and return those `a`s".

The code above is therefore equivalent to

```
example = [a | _ <- [1,2,3], a <- [4,5,6]]
```

or any other name instead of `_`.

For a predicate, you need a `Bool` expression, e.g.

```
evenNumbers = [a | a <- [1..100], even a]
```

In your case, the boolean expression is likely `` a `elem` combSet ``.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I'm from a mathematical background, and thought list comprehensions were identical to set definitions.

Answer (score 3):

`[a | a <- xs, a <- combSet]` is equivalent to `[a | x <- xs, a <- combSet]`, since the first `a` is being "shadowed" by the second one.  This always happens when there are nested redefinitions of the same identifier, e.g. in `\a -> ... (\a -> ....)`.

Turning on warnings with `-Wall` should spot this issue.

You could instead use `[a | a <- xs, elem a combSet]` to check that `a` occurs inside `combSet`.